# How to find the path of an mounted iso file?

Tags: command-line

I want the full path of the original iso file which was mounted into a (lets say `/media/iso`) directory. I don't know how to get that iso file path.

I tried `lsblk`,`sudo blkid` commands but nothing seems to work.

How do i find the path of an iso file which is currently mounted? Is there any command for that?

Answer (score 2):

Run the below command on terminal to view the original iso file path which is mounted inside `/media/iso` directory,

```
mount | awk '/\/media\/iso/ { print $1}'
```

To see the whole line(*iso path location and the mount point*),

```
mount | awk '/\/media\/iso/ { print $0}'
```

OR

```
mount | grep /media/iso
```

In the above `/media/iso` is the mountpoint where the iso file is actually mounted.`/\/media\/iso/` in the awk command is a regular expression to grab a line which contains the name `/media/iso`.You have to escape the forward slahes(like `/\/media\/iso/`) while you give it on an awk search regex.

```
$ mount | grep /media/iso
/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso on /media/iso type iso9660 (ro)
$ mount | awk '/\/media\/iso/ { print $1}'
/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
$ mount | awk '/\/media\/iso/ { print $0}'
/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso on /media/iso type iso9660 (ro)
```

You can also search by the file type as,

```
$ mount | awk '/iso9660/ { print $1}'
/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
$ mount | awk '/iso9660/'
/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso on /media/iso type iso9660 (ro)
```